# press G and move forward / away from the user?

Tags: edit-mode

is it possible to press G and move forward / away from the user?
I want to push & pull the face with proportional editing to create a rounded shape.

Comment: In the Transform Orientation panel you can choose View, then G and Z but you need to open a new 3D view to be able to move it as much as wanted because in frontal view it will be hard to estimate

Comment: looks like Normal transform orientation is what I looking for. Doesn't have to be projected from the user but works in similar ways. Thanks!

Comment: Oh ok so it's not from the user   ;)